# Increase optimization processing speed

Tags: mathematical-optimization, performance-tuning

As you know, sometimes numerically solving of optimization problems takes several minutes. For this reason 2 question came up to me:

1 - When one is abort the optimization procedure, how it is possible to obtain latest updated variables? For example, consider the code below: ([get data matrices from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9yj0ici6bdr14e/data_matrices.mat))

```
      imp = Import["data_matrices.mat", "LabeledData"];
      Atilt = "A0" /. imp;
      Btilt = "M1" /. imp;
      Ctilt = "M2" /. imp;

      T = 0.01;

      Xp = {{x + y*(T/2), y*T}, {1, 1}};
      Arbar = Atilt + Btilt.Xp.Ctilt;

      Ghat = Ctilt.Inverse[(IdentityMatrix[102] /. 1 -> z) - Arbar].Btilt;

      (* Ghat = {{g11, g12},{g21, g22}} *)
      g11 = Part[Ghat, 1, 1] /. z -> Exp[I w];
      g12 = Part[Ghat, 1, 2] /. z -> Exp[I w];
      g21 = Part[Ghat, 2, 1] /. z -> Exp[I w];
      g22 = Part[Ghat, 2, 2] /. z -> Exp[I w];

     (* find H_infty norm of Ghat *)
     f[x_, y_, w_] := Max[{Abs[g11] + Abs[g12], Abs[g21] + Abs[g22]}];


     g[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := NMaximize[{Evaluate[f[x, y, w]], 0 <= w <= 2.Pi}, {w, 0, 2.Pi}][[1]];

     FindMinimum[{g[x, y], 0.5 <= x <= 1.7, 0.7 <= y <= 1.3}, {x, 1}, {y, 1}]
```

If I abort the optimization, how can I find the latest `x` and `y`? (Is this a correct question?!)

2 - How can I change the code above to increase optimization processing speed?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

**Data matrices**:
     As it's obvious the `data_matrices.mat`(`A0`,`M1`,`M2`) created in MATLAB environment.

```
  del = 1;
  h = 0.01;   % Obtain discrete-time system; transfer function and state-space realization

  numG = 1; denG = conv([1 1],1);
  G = tf(numG,denG);
  Gd = c2d(G,h,'zoh');
  [numGd,den] = tfdata(Gd,'v'); 
  k = del/h;
  denGd = conv(den,[1 zeros(1,k)]);
  Gd = tf(numGd,denGd,h);

  ssGd = canon(Gd,'companion');
  A = ssGd.A; B = ssGd.B; C = ssGd.C;
  m = size(A);

  A0 = cell(2,2); Ar{1,1} = A; Ar{1,2} = zeros(m(1),1); Ar{2,1} = zeros(1,m(1)); Ar{2,2} = zeros(1,1);
  Br = cell(2,2); Br{1,1} = -B; Br{1,2} = zeros(m(1),1); Br{2,1} = zeros(1,1); Br{2,2} = ones(1);
  Cr = cell(2,2); Cr{1,1} = C; Cr{2,1} = zeros(1,m(1)); Cr{1,2} = zeros(1,1); Cr{2,2} = ones(1);
  M1 = cell2mat(Br);
  M2 = cell2mat(Cr);
```

Comment: For your first question, you can collect the latest used `x` and `y` with the `StepMonitor` option of `FindMinimum`.

Comment: Btw, it would be incredible helpful if you could provide a way to create a `data_matrices.mat` which can be used to run and test the code. Otherwise, it will be hard to give you help for optimization.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for `StepMonitor`. I added details about `data matrices.mat` file.